# OptaPlanner - overconstrained problem, with partitioning & virtual values

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to use OptaPlanner for a bus&order scheduling problem: there are orders, and buses, and we should schedule the orders to the buses with some category matching, and deadhead run minimization. Both the buses and the orders are `PlanningEntities`, as in the example VRP.

But the problem I'd like to solve is a bit overconstrained: there aren't enough buses to solve the problem optimally.

Currently, I'm creating virtual buses on the fly: I'm creating an initial solution with a greedy algorithm in a `customPhase`, and if I can't schedule an order to any bus I'll create a new virtual bus for it - yeah, I modify the `ProblemEntityCollection` from the customPhase. (Probably I should not do that, I know :'( )

This works fine - until I'd like to partition the whole optimization based on the date of the orders. After I config the partitioning, the `PartitionChangeMove::rebase` method throws an exception, 'cause it can't find the virtual bus in the main solution. (this is my guess)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The externalObject (Bus(id=e22c8407-c7b0-4af7-a6fd-4f1ba0635ef5, registrationSign=GENERATED-10) with planningId ((class Bus, e22c8407-c7b0-4af7-a6fd-4f1ba0635ef5)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class Bus).
```

As far as I see the `AbstractScoreDirector` uses multiple `LookUpManager`s, and each `LookUpManager` caches the IDs to the buses - so even if I add the virtual bus to all the solutions, the cache won't refresh everywhere.

I guess I should not create `PlanningEntities` from a `customPhase`, the way I do now. But is there a supported way to do this? Or should I generate these virtual buses before I start the solver at all?

Or do you have any better idea of how to solve this overconstrained problem?

Comment: Do you run the <customPhase> before or inside the <partitionedSearch> phase?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Inside. I have a solverConfig with one customPhase and multiple localSearches after that. My config gives me a better solution if I start the optimization for 3 days of data and I add +3 days of data every 2 minutes a couple of times than if I start the solver for x*3 days for x*2 minutes. As far as I understand this is a primitive way to partition my problem - I'd like to reproduce that in a supported way.

Comment: (currently I'm thinking about something like, start each partition with hundreds of virtual buses, and do a customPhase which merges these into the real buses after the partitioning ends...)